# Roll up with showing only first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to represent data in form of balance sheet .. but while using roll up same field is coming in all records. I want to show it in only first record and then show total in the end .

```
SELECT     [Mapping 1] = ISNULL([Mapping 1], 'Total'),
           [Mapping 2] = ISNULL([Mapping 2], 'Total mapping 2'),     
           [Mapping 3] = ISNULL([Mapping 3], 'Total_mapping_3'),
           FY_2012 = sum (FY_2012) ,
           FY_2013 = sum (FY_2013) ,
           FY_2014 = sum (FY_2014)
FROM (select * from dbo.Sheet1$ b where b.[IS/BS] = 'BS' ) a
GROUP BY ROLLUP([Mapping 1] , a.[Mapping 2] , a.[Mapping 3]  )
order by [Mapping 1] , a.[Mapping 2] desc ;
```

like in below i want to show asset and long term assets only once

```
Asset   Long term asset Deferred tax assets, net    2893072 2867543 2821122
Asset   Long term asset Other long term assets  7201098 7187156 7181692
Asset   Long term asset Plant, property, and equipment  10077126    10222498
Asset   Long term asset Total_mapping_3 23071316    23174636    23015602
```

Like

```
Asset   Long term asset Deferred tax assets, net    2893072 2867543 2821122
                        Other long term assets  7201098 7187156 7181692
                        Plant, property, and equipment  10077126    10222498    
                        Total_mapping_3 23071316    23174636    23015602
```